# Nexus Sites Repositories for npm projects

Tags: maven, npm

Nexus has a Site Repository feature for Maven projects, allowing them to publish a site to nexus:
https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager2/site-repositories

Is there a non-maven way of doing this that could be used by an npm project?
For example, using a RESTful endpoint or curl?

Comment: Sorry I'm not clear, is your end goal to have npm commands that create a site repository on NXRM2?

Comment: I think npm only became available in NXRM3. But yes, publish a site repository using npm, or curl or ssh. Just not maven.

Comment: npm is available as a format in both NXRM2 and NXRM3 but seems tangential =)  I don't know how to do what you're asking, I suspect it would be doable if someone were to write it.  The site format in NXRM2 (and raw format in NXRM3) just host files.  So, if you were to upload html (by any means), it would have it.  All the maven archetype documented in your link does is put all that together for you, iiuc.